# How to modify batch script to run as TrustedInstaller

Tags: batch-file, windows-services, runas

I have a toggle batch script that automatically Stops and Starts "WinDefend" Service. Except "WinDefend" Service can only be stopped as TrustedInstaller. So to make the script work, I first have to launch [NSudo](https://github.com/M2Team/NSudo/releases) then run the script. How can we modify this batch script so it automatically runs as TrustedInstaller using NSudo?

Download: [NSudo](https://github.com/M2Team/NSudo/releases/download/6.2/NSudo_6.2.1812.31_All_Binary.zip)

```
@echo off

sc query WinDefend | find /I "STATE" | find "STOPPED"
if errorlevel 1 goto :stop
goto :start

:stop
sc stop WinDefend

:start
net start | find /i "WinDefend">nul && goto :start
sc start WinDefend
```

Comment: Looks like `NSudo -U:T sc stop windefend` but all that information is quite readily available and self explanatory here: https://github.com/M2Team/NSudo/blob/master/Readme.md

Comment: Wow thanks. It's so crazy... I actually tried "NSudo -U:T -P:E cmd sc stop WinDefend"  and a few other command lines but couldn't make it work.

Comment: You might need the `-P:E` I don’t know. But it doesn’t look like you need `cmd` but if you do it is `cmd /c sc stop windefend`

Comment: It works without '-P:E' but I added '-ShowWindowMode:Hide' to hide a window

Comment: Modified the script too, to make it less rudundant

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @appleoddity I finally got it to work.

Also modified the script to make it less rudundant.

```
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0"
sc query WinDefend | find "STATE" | find "RUNNING" && goto :stop

:start
NSudo.exe -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide sc start WinDefend & exit /b

:stop
NSudo.exe -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide sc stop WinDefend & exit /b
```